# Update a column in all rows in db with second part of a column within the same row

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I'm trying to update all rows in my db to break apart name (last, first) to have last_name, first_name and display_name but I am not sure where to get the id of the current row being updated.  My current sql script is something along the lines of:

```
UPDATE user_profile 
SET last_name=(SELECT split_part(display_name,',',1) 
               FROM user_profile WHERE id=<current_id>;) 
WHERE last_name IS Null;
```

Comment: maybe something like this :`UPDATE user_profile SET last_name = split_part(display_name,',',1) WHERE last_name IS Null;`

Comment: Why have `WHERE` at all if you are going to do this for all rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify that current row id. A plain `update` operates in a per-row context. If you use a reference to `display_name`, it'll assume you mean the one in the current row.

```sql
UPDATE user_profile 
SET   last_name = split_part(display_name,',',1)
WHERE last_name IS null;
```

You can also split into the two fields in one go:

```sql
UPDATE user_profile 
SET (first_name, last_name)
  = (coalesce(first_name,
              split_part(display_name,',',2)),
     coalesce(last_name,
              split_part(display_name,',',1)) );
```

[`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) returns the first non-null value in its argument list, so if the field is already populated, it won't change it.

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/EtgMLd52)

---

If you really wanted to, you could alias both instances of the table and match them, like you would with any other table

```sql
UPDATE user_profile AS u1
SET last_name=(SELECT split_part(u2.display_name,',',1)
               FROM user_profile AS u2 WHERE u2.id=u1.id) 
WHERE last_name IS null;
```

and you don't necessarily need the subselect for that

```sql
UPDATE user_profile AS u1
SET last_name=split_part(u2.display_name,',',1)
FROM user_profile AS u2 
WHERE u2.id=u1.id
AND u1.last_name IS null;
```

That's handy when you want to specifically reference some ***other*** row in the same table.